# Call-time pass-by-reference does not generate E_DEPRECATED error

Tags: php

I'm encountering a consistency issue with an `E_DEPRECATED` message.

I have the following snippet of code that can be run on the command-line to demonstrate.

```
php -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors=1 -r 'function foo(&$bar) {return $bar->title . ".";} $bar = new stdClass(); $bar->title = "foobar"; print foo(&$bar) . PHP_EOL . PHP_VERSION . PHP_EOL;'
```

Readable version:

```
// error reporting set to E_ALL via command-line
function foo(&$bar) {
  return $bar->title . ".";
} 

$bar = new stdClass(); 
$bar->title = "foobar"; 

print foo(&$bar) . PHP_EOL . PHP_VERSION . PHP_EOL;
//        ^ this should raise E_DEPRECATED
```

I'm trying to trigger a `PHP Deprecated:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated` message with this snippet `foo(&$bar)` but for some reason it's not being raised on my local install.

I've passed it around to several other environments running various versions of php, different os's etc. and gotten different results:

EXPECTED:

```
mike@server:~$ php -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors=1 -r 'function foo(&$bar) {return $bar->title . ".";} $bar = new stdClass(); $bar->title = "foobar"; print foo(&$bar) . PHP_EOL . PHP_VERSION . PHP_EOL;'
PHP Deprecated:  Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in Command line code on line 1
foobar.
5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2
```

IN MY ENVIRONMENT:

```
mike@local:~$ php -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors=1 -r 'function foo(&$bar) {return $bar->title . ".";} $bar = new stdClass(); $bar->title = "foobar"; print foo(&$bar) . PHP_EOL . PHP_VERSION . PHP_EOL;'
foobar.
5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2
```

What could be causing this?

#### Update:

I did the following to verify that deprecated errors are still being thrown in my environment:

```
mike@local:~$ php -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors=1 -r 'eregi("test", "test");'

Deprecated: Function eregi() is deprecated in Command line code on line 1
```

Comment: *(tip)* `error_reporting(-1)` enables all error levels for reporting.

Comment: @Gordon Good to know! That will be helpful in the future. note: I tried updating my command to use error_reporting=-1 but got the same results.

Comment: What does `php -d error_reporting=-1 -d display_errors=1 -r 'function f(&$b) {} f(&$c); var_dump(ini_get("error_reporting"), PHP_VERSION);'` give?

Comment: @salathe `string(2) "-1" string(16) "5.3.5-1ubuntu7.2"` on my machine. But on others it throws the Deprecated msg. Also, your example is much cleaner than mine. Mind if I update my question to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By any chance, is your [`allow_call_time_pass_reference`](http://php.net/allow_call_time_pass_reference) setting enabled in php.ini?

```
; This directive allows you to enable and disable warnings which PHP will issue
; if you pass a value by reference at function call time. Passing values by
; reference at function call time is a deprecated feature which will be removed
; from PHP at some point in the near future. The acceptable method for passing a
; value by reference to a function is by declaring the reference in the functions
; definition, not at call time. This directive does not disable this feature, it
; only determines whether PHP will warn you about it or not. These warnings
; should enabled in development environments only.
; Default Value: On (Suppress warnings)
; Development Value: Off (Issue warnings)
; Production Value: Off (Issue warnings)
; http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
```

Especially note:

```
; Default Value: On (Suppress warnings)
```

Comment: Bingo. Once I added `allow_call_time_pass_reference=0` to the test above I started receiving the error. Not sure how that setting got into my php.ini. Thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

Passing to a function by reference has been deprecated for quite some time (I believe since PHP 5 was introduced?) and is why you're getting the warning. Simply calling `foo($bar)` will pass the parameter by reference since you've stated that in the function definition.

The fact that you're getting different results means that there's either a different in the php.ini file or the error reporting number is off (I believe it changes between versions).

Comment: I know what the error means and how to fix it. I need to know why it's not being raised in my situation where I've explicitly set error_reporting. "*there's either a different in the php.ini file*" That's what I'm asking about. What php setting could effect this?

Comment: -1: You haven't answered the question here. I suspect that you also didn't read it!

Comment: My second paragraph directly addresses the question asked, albeit not in a conclusive way. I don't see how I didn't read the question.